# Getting full path to project directory (both in Visual Studio debug and release)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the path of files I've added or created to my project. Currently on the root of the project I have a data folder `<projectName>\data\..`. I've been trying to get the file path and check to see if a file exists, but am having trouble getting the path to be dynamic and correct.

My main attempts have been using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` but those end up with something like `G:\..\<projectName>\<projectName>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\`. Where the first `<projectName>` has the .sln file and the second `<projectName>` has my data, bin, etc folders.

I want to be able to check that path while both in debug in my IDE and once I release the program. So effectively finding the path `G:\..\<projectName>\<projectName>\data\<actualFile>`. Maybe I misunderstand how I should be setting up my directories in my project folder. Since I know that running debug will put the .exe in bin\debug. So unless there is some way to change the working directory independent of the exe while in debug (Which I assume won't really help much and cause the same problem once I release) or some other setting in Visual Studio I'm not exactly sure what to do. Also I don't want to put some static folder path as I want to keep it all contained into the project's directory.

Conceisely, how do I get a specific file path in my project directory, and have the path work for both debugging and release?

Comment: is the data folder required in the final release? or is it just used for debugging? why does it need to be put in the project's root directory instead of inside the same directory as the exe?

Comment: The data folder will be required for release. On release sure the project structure would probably have the data folder beside the exe, but I can't figure out how to mimic that while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting for this purpose.

Select the files in data folder, right click, and select `Properties` from the context menu, and then set the 'Copy to output directory' property to 'Copy Always'.

In this way, every time you build the project, the data folder will be automatically copied to `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! That was causing a very confusing headache, especially when comparing this to something like Java or C++. But hey part of the learning experience. I'll have to learn more on how to publish and package it in the future, but feel this helped solve a very confusing issue to bang through most of it for awhile.

Comment: Glad it helps. This is something built into the IDE centuries ago, to eliminate the need to copy files to the output folder manually and repeatedly. The good thing is that once you learn it is just an easy IDE feature, you will never forget.